# Slide out CSS box not responding when shrinking the web browser

Tags: html, css

First off, sorry about the title, its a weird topic.

Secondly, I am creating a website for a college course and I have created a slide out section on my page. It works fine until I make the web browser smaller. This is my browser full screen:

[image: sn]

As you can see on the left, it is all fine and nothing is wrong.

[image: sdinv]
This  is what happens when I make the browser smaller.
Please could you guys help me with this problem, I want it to be able to stay in the same place
Here is my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/54VpY/

```
#slideout_admin {
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
background-color: #ccc;
border-color: gold gold gold -moz-use-text-color;
border-image: none;
border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
border-style: solid solid solid hidden;
border-width: 2px 2px 2px medium;
left: 0;
padding: 12px 0;
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
top: 250px;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
width: 35px;
z-index: 100;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to figure out the exact location but it looks like your styling for slideout_inner_admin is inside a media query. As soon as the size is changing that div is losing all of its styling and showing on screen instead of to the right.

Edit: 
Looks like it is the media query on line 706

```
@media screen and (min-width : 790px)...
```

If I remove that the menu works, not sure exactly how you want to specify that behavior though.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is right here:

```
#slideout_admin {
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
background-color: #ccc;
border-color: gold gold gold -moz-use-text-color;
border-image: none;
border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
border-style: solid solid solid hidden;
border-width: 2px 2px 2px medium;
left: 0;
padding: 12px 0;
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
top: 250px;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
width: 35px;
z-index: 100;
}
```

You have that inside of the following Media Query

```
@media screen and (max-width : 790px)
```

Which means, you don't have the styles in place for anything BELOW 790px in width. Try changing that to `@media screen and (min-width : 790px)`, you'll see that it works just fine for resolutions below 790px but not for those that are higher. You need to make sure your styles are defined for all resolutions.

Comment: If you want the styles to be the same regardless of screen size, then you wouldn't even need this inside of a media query, I'd simply pull it, and related styles, out and move it above your media queries.